# How remove repetition of content?

Tags: command-line, bash, scripts, regex

I have a file `aq.txt` contain the following content:

```
WP_021815421.1  OG5_132922  deth|YP_182312  3   -07 42.35   81.7
WP_021815427.1  OG5_128110  rbal|NP_868155  1   -55 50.72   53.2
WP_012456834.1  NO_GROUP    bsui|NP_700181  8   -53 48.18   62
WP_084606289.1  OG5_132922  aful|NP_069703  5   -28 57.00   92.6
WP_084606284.1  OG5_153487  bpse|YP_331974.1    6   -78 48.87   91.4
```

and another file `ar.txt` contain the following conatent:

```
WP_007394757.1  OG5_129150  cbur|NP_820894  7   -12 84.09   100
WP_010195908.1  OG5_130915  yent|YP_001007837.1 6   -16 70.42   100
WP_011281115.1  OG5_128110  rbal|NP_868155  1   -56 51.67   52.3
WP_010196670.1  OG5_126760  yent|YP_001008069.1 7   -46 85.44   100
WP_010196689.1  OG5_128312  sent|NP_458465  8   -36 68.81   100
WP_010196702.1  OG5_126678  sfle|NP_709098  7   -52 81.30   100
WP_011281110.1  OG5_132922  deth|YP_182312  1   -07 38.82   81.7
WP_011281234.1  NO_GROUP    bsui|NP_700181  8   -53 48.18   62
WP_011281111.1  OG5_132922  aful|NP_069703  5   -28 55.88   94.4
WP_010196711.1  OG5_126722  sent|NP_458477  2   -53 73.29   96.4
WP_010196728.1  OG5_126681  bpse|YP_335116.1    1   -42 80.36   86.8
```

I want to extract only matching pattern (based on `OG number`) so I write the following script:

```
OG5_132922  aq  WP_021815421.1
OG5_132922  ar  WP_011281110.1
OG5_132922  ar  WP_011281111.1
OG5_128110  aq  WP_021815427.1
OG5_128110  ar  WP_011281115.1
OG5_132922  aq  WP_021815421.1
OG5_132922  ar  WP_011281110.1
OG5_153487  aq  WP_084606284.1
```

I mean that if it found OG number twice or more time then only first matched should be printed. Can anyone guide me?

Comment: But in your desired output there are still multiple occurrences of the same "OG number", like 3x `OG5_132922`. I don't exactly understand your requirements, the description seems to be conflicting with your example.

Comment: But shouldn't line `OG5_132922  psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_011281111.1` (the third line in the output example) be removed then too? It's the second occurrence of that OG number with the arcticus file.

Comment: That also should remove.

Comment: `cut -d$'\t' -f 2 psychrobacter_aquaticus > set1` will put the same group several times in `set1`. Perhaps you want to remove the duplicates there first (``cut -d$'\t' -f 2 psychrobacter_aquaticus | sort -u > set1`)

Comment: @xenoid ok removed this duplication, but the duplication (as mention above) is same, what should I do now?

Comment: The loop over set1 contents can be replaced by the much more efficient `grep -i set1 *.txt`

Comment: Sorry, it doesn't work.

Comment: To answer your question about `sort`: to sort based on the second column `awk '{print $1 "\t" $2}' psychrobacter_aquaticus.txt | sort -u -k2`. See [`man sort`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/sort.1.html).

Comment: The question is easier to answer when you make your desired output *actually look like* what you want. Reading comments I get the impression it doesn't.

Answer (score 2):

**Problem:**

- Print the second field, the filename without the extension, then the first field.
- Separate the output fields with a TAB.
- Omit lines containing `NO_GROUP`.
- In the output file, the combination of the first and second field must be unique (they constitute a unique key): any further records having the same key are to be discarded.

**Solution:**

```
awk 'FNR == 1 {delete a} !/NO_GROUP/ && !($2 in a) {print $2"\t"gensub(/\..*$/, "", 1, FILENAME)"\t"$1; a[$2]++;}' *.txt
```

**Test run results:**

```
OG5_132922      psychrobacter_aquaticus WP_021815421.1
OG5_128110      psychrobacter_aquaticus WP_021815427.1
OG5_153487      psychrobacter_aquaticus WP_084606284.1
OG5_129150      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_007394757.1
OG5_130915      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_010195908.1
OG5_128110      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_011281115.1
OG5_126760      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_010196670.1
OG5_128312      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_010196689.1
OG5_126678      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_010196702.1
OG5_132922      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_011281110.1
OG5_126722      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_010196711.1
OG5_126681      psychrobacter_arcticus  WP_010196728.1
```

**Sorting:**

If you want to sort the results, just pipe them to `sort` or `sort -k2,2` depending on the desired output.